# Pandas copy column names from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that we have two pandas data frames. The first one hasn't got column names:

```
no_col_names_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]))
```

The second has:

```
col_names_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10,2,3], [4,45,6], [7,18,9]]),
                           columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

What I want to do is to get copy column *names* from the `col_names_df` to `no_col_names_df` so that the following data frame is created:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       2       3
1   4       5       6
2   7       8       9
```

I've tried the following:

```
new_df_with_col_names = pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df, columns=col_names_df.columns)
```

but instead of values from the `no_col_names_df` I get `NaN`s.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just like you have used columns from the dataframe with column names, you can use values from the dataframe without column names:

`new_df_with_col_names = pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df.values, columns=col_names_df.columns)`

---

> ```
> In [4]: new_df_with_col_names = pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df, columns=col_names_df.columns)
>
> In [5]: new_df_with_col_names
> Out[5]:
>    col1  col2  col3
> 0   NaN   NaN   NaN
> 1   NaN   NaN   NaN
> 2   NaN   NaN   NaN
>
> In [6]: new_df_with_col_names = pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df.values, columns=col_names_df.columns)
>
> In [7]: new_df_with_col_names
> Out[7]:
>    col1  col2  col3
> 0     1     2     3
> 1     4     5     6
> 2     7     8     9
> ```

Comment: that's exactly my answer btw, posting an answer that adds no value versus a previously shared answer is a behavior that should not be encouraged

Comment: We posted in the seconds interval from each other. When I started writting my answer yours wasn't there yet. No evil intentions here.

Comment: Not saying there's an intent. But since you posted the same thing as me, the criterion is to remove the one that got posted later.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to directly assign the columns of `col_names_df` to the ones of `no_col_names_df`:

```
no_col_names_df.columns = col_names_df.columns

     col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2     7     8     9
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df, columns=col_names_df.columns)
```

gives you all 'NaN' dataframe because you pass a dataframe to construct a new dataframe and assign new `columns` to it. Pandas essentially constructs identical dataframe and does `reindex` along `axis 1`on it. In other words, that command is equivalent to doing:

```
no_col_names_df.reindex(col_names_df.columns, axis=1)
```

You need either change directly `no_col_names_df.columns` or passing `no_col_names_df.values`

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting nan then most likely the issue is the data parameter, try this:

```
new_df_with_col_names = pd.DataFrame(data=no_col_names_df.values, columns=col_names_df.columns)
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2     7     8     9
```

Comment: would like some feedback on the downvote, if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the simplest one and it is worked for me;

no_col_names_df.columns = col_names_df.columns